# Comparing ASTER/SRTM dataset in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, srtm, aster

Currently I am working with two data set ASTER and SRTM. I want to check their accuracy with reference to toposheet.

How would I do that in ArcGIS Desktop 10.4?

I want to check accuracy in terms of area and length of my study area.

Comment: i am yet to figure out how to compare these two data-set. I want to check weather there is any substantial difference in the derived DEM of the two satellite imagery which I am using

Comment: What format is your topo data? Raster topo map, topographic vectors (contours, spot elevations, survey controls etc)?

Comment: It is in contour format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digitize manually the polygons on the raster data which you want to compare and do the comparison.

Comment: what short of comparison do i need in this case ?